# Save copy of a photo from Google Places API Place Photos using curl

Tags: php, curl, google-places-api

I'm trying to grab a photo from Google Place Photos using curl and save it on my server.

The request format as per the [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) is like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

So I tried this function:

```
function download_image1($image_url, $image_file){
    $fp = fopen ($image_file, 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // enable if you want
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // output to file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000); // some large value to allow curl to run for a long time
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Enable this line to see debug prints
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); // closing curl handle
    fclose($fp); // closing file handle
}

download_image1($photo, "test.jpg");
```

..where `$photo` holds the request url.

This is not working, it saves an empty image with header errors, it probably is because the request is not the actual url of the photo. Also, in the request url, it's not possible to know which image extension I'm going to get (jpg, png, gif, etc) so that's another problem.

Any help on how to save the photos appreciated.

EDIT: I get the header errors "Can't read file header" in my image viewer software when I try to open the image. The script itself doesn't show any errors.

Comment: What is the error you get ?
beside that why not simply use file_get_contents() ?

You have an google api key do you ? It wont work otherwise

"The response of a successful Place Photo request will be an image. The type of the image will depend upon the type of the originally submitted photo.

"Note that you'll need to replace the photo reference and key in this example in order for the request to work in your application."

"If your request exceeds your available quota, the server will return an HTTP 403 status and display the below image to indicate that the quota has been exceeded:"

Comment: I don't get any script errors, test.jpg gets saved but it's 0KB and it shows an error when I try opening it with my image viewer(irfan view), the error is "Can't read file header". Yes I have api key alright in the request, I just omitted it here. I don't use file_get_contents() because I read somewhere that for https, I'll need apache with SSL support which I don't have installed and with curl that is not needed.

Comment: @nixoschu just to clarify better, if I type the request url in my browser address bar, it redirects and shows the image fine, so there's nothing wrong with the request url, when I use the same request url in the script above, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try curl_getinfo() and curl_error()

to become more informations ?

if there is an error google should return one :
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos#error_messages

Comment: @nixoschu there was no error, the photo request URL is working perfectly when typed in the browser's address bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution here:
http://kyleyu.com/?q=node/356

It gives a very useful function to return the actual URL after redirection:

```
function get_furl($url)
    {
    $furl = false;
    // First check response headers
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    // Test for 301 or 302
    if(preg_match('/^HTTP\/\d\.\d\s+(301|302)/',$headers[0]))
        {
        foreach($headers as $value)
            {
            if(substr(strtolower($value), 0, 9) == "location:")
                {
                $furl = trim(substr($value, 9, strlen($value)));
                }
            }
        }
    // Set final URL
    $furl = ($furl) ? $furl : $url;
    return $furl;
    }
```

So you pass the Google Place Photo request uRL to this function and it returns the actual URL of the photo after the redirection which then can be used with CURL. It also explains that sometimes, the curl option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` doesn't always work.

Comment: super helpful! still works in October 2021!!!

Comment: be careful, the first link seems broken, it performs a lot of redirects but your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23540352/2979237

We can minimize the above code to change as adding 1 as the second parameter of get_header() function like `$headers = get_headers($url, 1);`. that will return the associate values.